# FromBody parameter (as jobject and string) is always null

Tags: javascript, c#, json, http-post, frombodyattribute

Ive been reading the sundry posts about "From body param is null" and none of the solutions in them have solved my problem.

I have this ajax call

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/User/UpdateSessionNoteBase/' + noteData['noteId'],
        contentType: "charset=utf-8",
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(noteData),})
```

and this C# function call (.Net FW)

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
public JsonResult UpdateSessionNoteBase([FromUri]int id, [FromBody]string data)
```

I have tried including contentType:"application\json" and making the datatype of the [FromBody] param a JObject, and keeping the variabe as a string, and nothing Iv tried makes that param have a value. The fromURI parameter works fine regardless.

Does anyone have any insights into this?